# jquery.ui hide with fixed element

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I want to use the `hide()` function of jquery to hide messages that are flashing on a page.

When I load the page, I want to display it for 5 sec then make it disapear.

```
$('#flash-message').show("clip");

setTimeout(function() {
    $("#flash-message").hide("clip", { direction: 'vertical' }, 1000);
}, 5000);
```

It doesn't do the "animation" if I use a fixed or absolute position and I need to put the message on top of the page with a fixed position.

Is there a work around for that? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

To call events when the page loads use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   //code here 
});
```

If you only want to use "clip" try this:

```
$("#flash-message").hide("clip", {direction: "vertical"}, 5000)
```

or else try using animate:

```
$('#flash-message').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    direction: "left",
    }, 5000, function() {
        $(this).hide();
});
```

Or something more simple:

```
$("#flash-message").click(function() {
  $("#flash-message").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: .animate dowsn't do the same thing has .hide("clip") but is close enough to the desired effect. If I can't find why .hide("clip") doesn't work, I will use this one.

Comment: @LucBrosseau, you can use `$("#flash-message").toggle("clip");`